# tricky question, shortest distance between subspaces of matrices of $2\times2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I hope you can help me, I'm very new to linear algebra.

given $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $M$ the euclidean space of matrices $2\times2$ with the usual operations of addition of matrices and multiplication by an scalar with a matrix, with inner product $\langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{Trace}(AB^T)\ $if $S=\{A\in M|AB = BA = 0\}$ is the linear subspace of $M$ and $C=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ a matrix in $M$.

Find in $S$ the closest matrix to $C$.

What I did so far is the following:

According to the rules above, the matrix B is invertible due to the fact the it's determinant is not zero, so using it in the definition of the subspace $S$ we could multiply with it's inverse like this $ABB^{-1}=0B^{-1} \implies A = 0$ , so the subspace $S=\{0\}?$, it will mean that the closest matrix to $C$ is the $0$ matrix?.

Hope you can help me to validate my result or am I missing something?, how would you find a basis for $S$ in the case that it's determinant was zero e.g $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Cheers.

Comment: Can you plz tell what is definition of closest matrix ? I'm also new.

Comment: Are you sure that you wrote down the correct definition of $S$?

Comment: For the first part, you are right, for $B$ an invertible matrix, $A$ would have to be $0$, so $S = \{0\}$ and the problem is trivial. But I'm not sure how to find a basis for $S$ for arbitrary $B$, although given a specific $B$ it isn't hard.

Comment: @AlexProvost, I've already realized something, the unique product defined between vectors $A$ and $B$ is the inner product so the correct expression should have been $<A,B>=<B,A>=0$, don't you think?

Comment: Any thoughts about my answer, dennis?

Answer (score 1):

For the last question, let $A=\pmatrix{r&s\cr t&u\cr}$ and work out conditions on $r,s,t,u$ for $AB=BA=0$ --- it's not that hard. Then calculate the trace of $CD^t$ for $D$ of the type you have found, and minimize it.